# Use external libraries in Mule ESB

Tags: java, spring-boot, mule

I've developed a small Spring Boot app and I've packaged it in a jar file.
Using Anypoint Studio, I am trying to develop a class in a Mule project that will implement an interface located in my jar.
I've used this [guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/adding-and-removing-user-libraries) and I added the library in the referenced libraries of my project but I don't understand the second step of the guide and my interface cannot be found when I type "implements MyInterface".

[image]

Is what I'm trying to do possible or will I need to have my interface inside my Mule project rather than in my external jar?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say? Also, what's in your `myproj.xml`? did you add the reference to your library in [step 2](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/adding-and-removing-user-libraries#adding-user-libraries)?

Comment: At the moment my flow is super simple. I'm reading from a file and I then have a java component. My goal is for this Java component to have access to my classes inside the jar (implement an interface or make a call to utility classes etc) What do I need to do for step 2? Should I type "myproj.xml" or should I add an xml file inside my jar and type this file's name?